# Which character representation is \300-306\ in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a function to remove accents from strings. It uses many regex like`/[\300-\306]/g`, `/[\340-\346]/g`, `/[\310-\313]/g`, `/[\350-\353]/g` to reference a range of accented characters like. [\300-\306] represents [Á, Ã, Â, À..]. I searched about this representation but didn't find any reference about it. I also think it isn't Ascii, unicode, utf8 since this numbers are different from their respective representation of these characters. What representation is that?

Comment: [Octal codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#In_computers), see `Òct` in [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just octal representations of the byte values. `\300` is 192 decimal.

Comment: Nice, is it a requirement to use the octal representation when working with regex ? Or can I also use the decimal representation ?

Comment: There's no way to specify a byte with its decimal representation that I know of, only octal (`\300`) or hexidecimal (`\xc0`).